# Find the "easter egg"

Tags: treasure-hunt

There's a little surprise somewhere on this site...

http://easter_egg_hunt.andrewfaraday.com/

Where is it?
What is it?

---

Addendum (full disclosure):

- The link is to a working application running on my personal web domain.
- There is no advertising or other revenue generation in that area of the site.
- I'm not collecting analytics data on site views, but it does inherently collect data on games (namely, when the game was played and how many guesses it took).

Comment: I got server error btw ._.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is an off-site “hunt” directing users to what seems to be the OP’s site (making this self promotion).  Puzzles should be self contained, not rely on offsite resources that could vanish at any time.

Comment: @Rubio There is no end of off-site resources used in these puzzles, they're just usually a lot more complex.

Comment: The firewall at my work blocks this server for being (potentially) malicious.

Comment: @Rubio I'm not sure I completely understand the objection. Yes, I spent some time constructing the puzzle, and as it's an active piece of software I'm not really able to host it on SE. I'm not advertising, or promoting any of my other work behind that link, there's no revenue generated by it. So what's the issue?

Comment: @Rubio - I can see your point, and maybe longterm it may be appropriate, but I must say that I enjoyed the hunt so - is it may be worth leaving it up for a bit - can AJ confirm there is no particular benefit from the site traffic? Sorry I'm rather new here so I don't know what the general practice is here.

Comment: @tom A quick look at the site will show you there's no ads displayed, the dev console will tell you there's not even an analytics tracker running there. I realise it's on the domain for my personal site, but that was just the simplest way to deploy it. I could release some analytics data for the main site, but I sincerely doubt there'll be a noticeable change, day on day.

Comment: Two issues with this post. First, SE considers *undisclosed self promotion* as [spam](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/help/promotion) and such posts may be flagged and/or deleted as such; Puzzling has had some issues with this in the past, so we are rather careful to curtail it. See also [How not to be a spammer](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4340) for more information on this. Secondly, see [this post](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/a/6070) for info about how/what off-site resources should and should not be used, and why; the other answer on that question is also good.

Comment: AJ - I would delete that last comment, it is tough enough being a moderator and having gone to the trouble of writing a long answer about this issue it we are going over ground that has been covered before....  I **really** like your puzzle AJ, but I can't see a way around  the SE policies on this - so I think @Rubio is just trying to keep things right on this site. Your puzzle looks fine, but the next person who has a link might be exposing us all to something nasty. I feel bad about it because you have created a good fun puzzle.

Comment: AJFaraday, my followup comment here was a courtesy to you to point out where on local Meta we’ve already discussed these types of things before. I am on mobile and just finding and linking to those posts was tedious enough. I don’t think my attempt to extend you that courtesy warrants your snark, but it hopefully provides you and others some context for why this post needs to be closed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got after:

> 12 turns

to this link

> http://easter_egg_hunt.andrewfaraday.com/surprise
>  which leads to some ASCII art saying 'Happy Easter' and shows 3 eggs.

Answer (score 2):

I got:

> http://easter_egg_hunt.andrewfaraday.com/surprise, in 7 turns, and it's 3 easter eggs. thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I got

> {"x":"right","y":"right","url":"http://easter_egg_hunt.andrewfaraday.com/surprise","turns":10} with code bkhfjqsjqhmjyctctqbr